# MYSQL server instance 8.0.13 automatically turned off and on randomly

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I have installed `mysql 8.0.13 server` with mysql community edition on `Mac OS (10.14.1) Mojava`. 
Next day i was unable to connect with mysql server. I start mysql instance and it turned to OFF mode as shown in figure.

[image]

I tried multiple solutions like;

> 1. Update file com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist keepAlive attribute to true
> 2. change connection timeout from 180 to 280.
> 3. No port is listening to 3306
> 4. Firewall disable

Kindly tell what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

**This worked for me  in MAC...**

open Terminal and write the following

This will check all the instances that are currently running.

1) ps -ef | grep mysql

If you found any process Id with the above command.

2) sudo kill -9 [PID]

Where [PID] is the process id next to username like 5098

so it will be kill 5098

now you will restart again using the mysql server pane or by command

mysql.server start

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is configured to connect on 3306. Sometimes MySQL configured itself on non-default port like 3307 or other. You can check by using following command.

> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';

Comment: yes it is listening to port 3306. but the issue is that is suddenly turns off again. when i try to start using system preference.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well on Ubuntu and it was because I had different versions in different locations. So a find to kill and remove them freed up the default port and it was happy ever after...haha

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why it worked, but I thought I'd share (because killing/stopping and restarting didn't work for me):

I've downloaded the tool [DBngin](https://dbngin.com/) and noticed that I had a MariaDB and a PostgreSQL DB running. After I'd stopped these processes, MySQL worked fine.